# Google Page Speed Insights - Basic Authentication

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am current using `npm psi` to do psi tests against a site which is publicly accessible (except with basic authentication).

All of my attempts to use the username:password@ convention have failed me thus far for psi and psi only.

I was wondering if I was missing anything?

```
{ [Error: PageSpeed is currently unable to fetch this URL. Please try again later.] code: 400, noStack: true }
```

Comment: You get the same response from https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
- I guess it's not the psi module that has a problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow pagespeed insights to http basic authentication sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65322808/how-to-allow-pagespeed-insights-to-http-basic-authentication-sites)

Answer (score -2):

You need to create an api key, and then use the key in your request

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=YOUR_URL_HERE&key=XXX_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE';
```

Follow these instructions
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v2/first-app#before_starting

Comment: not sure how this helps with basic authentication, which is what the question about OP is about.