# How to allow pagespeed insights to http basic authentication sites?

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

How to allow pagespeed insights to http basic authentication sites?
It is returning error as follows even though I mentioned the username and password as below format.

*Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED)*

*https://username:password@www.example.com*

e.g curl https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://username:password@www.example.com

Comment: Have you filed an issue with Google about this?

Answer (score 1):

Our method is to send the URL as `https://username:password@website.com`.

Same results. Normally this is sufficient bypass for other dev tools and scanners. Pagespeed Insights cannot do it.

Comment: Have you or @vivek-kumar or OP filed an issue with Google about this?

Answer (score 1):

This method does not seem to be working anymore - `https://username:password@website.com`

But one can check pagespeed insights through lighthouse which provides same results.

[image]

[GTMetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) is another way to check pagespeed insights.

You can pass the url like this - `https://username:password@website.com`